# Expectation as unique linear functional

Tags: probability-theory

A textbook on Probability theory by A. Obretenov I'm reading (in Bulgarian) has the following:

Let $(\Omega, \mathbb{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space.

For a simple random variable $\xi(\omega) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i I[A_i]$ (where $I[A_i]$ is the indicator of event $A_i$), they define
$$\mathbb{E}\xi = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \mathbb{P}I[A_i]$$

Then they state the following:

**Lemma.** The expectation operator defined above is the unique linear functional of the space of simple random variables, which satisfies:

- $\mathbb{E}[I[\Omega]] = 1$
- If $\xi \ge 0$ then $\mathbb{E}[\xi] \ge 0$
- If $\xi_n(\omega) \downarrow 0$ for each $\omega$, then $\mathbb{E}\xi_n \downarrow 0$ ($\downarrow$ denotes monotonically decreasing convergent sequence).

I'm trying to understand in what sense can we talk about uniqueness here, since clearly changing the probability measure will change the expectation without violating the conditions.

Comment: Well, all three ingredients of the probability space $(\Omega,\Bbb F,\Bbb P)$ are kept fixed.

Comment: @Berci True. But the it looks to me than expectation for an alternative measure $\mathbb{P}_1$ satisfies the three conditions given for the original space with $\mathbb{P}$.

Comment: What is the meaning of $ E(\Omega)$?

Comment: @TodorMarkov I think the question means to vary the functions while keeping the measure space fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The expectation operator is the unique linear operator satisfying the conditions you have given which extends the definition you have given on simple functions. Obviously, if you use a different probability measure, you will have a different expectation of some simple function.